# Can TGF beta family induce all somatic stem cells?

Tags: stem-cells

I think this is not possible.
Conclusion about this preview article *TGF-$\beta$ family signaling in stem cells*:

> While TGF-$\beta$ family signaling regulates stemness of normal and cancer stem cells, its effects are diverse and depend on the cell types and physiological state of the cells.

**Can TGF-$\beta$  induce all somatic stem cells?**

Comment: What do you mean by induce?

Comment: @Chris Induction. You can think it as sending a positive signal. I think it does not need growth value. Only that some process is induced to start or made stronger - not inhibited here.

Comment: But what do you want to induce? Differentiation? Migration? Proliferation? Retreat into a nice? This is a pretty broad topic at the moment.

Comment: TO be induced by a TGF-$\beta$ ligand, a cell has to express one of its cognate receptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signalling in the TGFβ pathway normally puts a brake on the progress of cells through the cell cycle - it counteracts the action of myc for example, partly by regulating the expression of myc. In [Burkitt's lymphoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burkitt%27s_lymphoma) myc escapes this regulation because of a chromosomal translocation, tipping the regulatory balance over to uncontrolled cell growth.

This anti-proliferative action of TGFβ signalling is so critical that you might expect it to be ubiquitous in cells, and [the expression atlas entry for the TGFβ receptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TGF_beta_receptor_2) is consistent with this.

Comment: So in naturally occurring somatic cells, the answer is yes because this antiproliferation action. Think now about induced somatic cells (those artificially derived from somatic stem cells). Can this same behaviour occur in all induced stem cells? I do not understand if this behaviour can proceed into processed cases and when we do not have such a behaviour on stem cells derived from somatic stem cells.